# Inertia network status 302

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I'm using Laravel Inertia and React
When i tried to post new user to backend its getting 302 network status like so :

CreateUser.jsx :

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    post(route('users.store'), { data, onSuccess: () => reset() })
}
```

UserController :

```
public function store(UserRequest $request)
{
    $attributes = $request->toArray();
    User::create($attributes);

    return back()->with([
        'type' => 'success',
        'message' => 'User was cretaed.'
    ]);
}
```

UserRequest :

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => ['required','alpha'],
        'username' => ['unique:users','required','alphanum'],
        'email' => ['unique:users','required','email'],
        'password' => ['required', Password::defaults()],
        'location' => ['required']
    ];
}
```

what i've get so far :

[image: request]

**Update**
I tried to access the subseq GET req response, turn out there was a validation error :
[image: response]

The error itself already handled, but the error notification never came out :

```
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react'
import React from 'react'

export default function CreateUser({errors}) {
    const { data, setData, post, reset } = useForm({
        name: '',
        username: '',
        email: '',
        location: '',
        password: ''
    });

    const onChange = (e) => setData({...data, [e.target.id]: e.target.value})

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        post(route('users.store'), { data, onSuccess: () => reset() })
    }


    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header">Create New User</div>
            <div className="card-body">
                <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <div className="mb-3">
                            <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name" name="name" value={data.name} onChange={onChange}/>
                            {errors && (<div className="text-danger mt-1">{errors.name}</div>)}
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <div className="mb-3">
                                    <label htmlFor="username" className="form-label">Username</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="username" name="username" value={data.username} onChange={onChange}/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <div className="mb-3">
                                    <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">Email</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="email" name="email" value={data.email} onChange={onChange}/>
                                    {errors && (<div className="text-danger mt-1">{errors.email}</div>)}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <div className="mb-3">
                                    <label htmlFor="location" className="form-label">Location</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="location" name="location" value={data.location} onChange={onChange}/>
                                    {errors && (<div className="text-danger mt-1">{errors.location}</div>)}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <div className="mb-3">
                                    <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" className="form-control" id="password" name="password" value={data.password} onChange={onChange}/>
                                    {errors && (<div className="text-danger mt-1">{errors.password}</div>)}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: 302 is the appropriate response code when using POST. If you inspect the subsequent GET request, you should be able to see that you are successfully redirected.

Comment: @LinusJuhlin i see, however i tried to investigate the get response and got another problem, please see my updated question

Comment: How are you defining the `errors`? Are you using `usePage()` ?

Comment: @LinusJuhlin i didn't use usePage(), please see my updated code, i've add the entire code,

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Images should only be used when an issue can't be demonstrated any other way, and when used should be cropped to the absolute minimum size needed to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I still do not see you using `usePage()`. You need to use it to access the errors in [the shared data](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data).

Comment: @LinusJuhlin thank you, this is what i was looking for, 
I tought by using the useForm() and pass the props would be sufficient
but anw it worked as desired !

Comment: @owf I added an answer with an explanation for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use shared data in your React.js pages, you need to make use of `usePage()`, which is how you access the props.

Here's an example [from the docs](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data#flash-messages):

```
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react'

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  const { flash } = usePage().props

  return (
    <main>
      <header></header>
      <content>
        {flash.message && (
          <div class="alert">{flash.message}</div>
        )}
        {children}
      </content>
      <footer></footer>
    </main>
  )
}
```